# Django template language and javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

The html code below produces two links that when hovered will output the corresponding audio file.  My question is if I have a table of links stored in a Django database how do I output it in the javascript so that using the Django template language I can loop over the table of links to populate the window.onload function? Or is there a more efficient way?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        // collecting elements
        var welcomeSound = document.getElementById('welcomeSound');
        var welcomeTxt = document.getElementById('welcomeTxt');

        var sdSound = document.getElementById('shutdownSound');
        var sdTxt = document.getElementById('shutdownTxt');
        //playing welcome sound on mouse over
        welcomeTxt.onmouseover = function() {
            welcomeSound.play();
            return false;
        };

        sdTxt.onmouseover = function() {
            sdSound.play();
            return false;
        };

    };
</script>
</head>
<html>
<section>
    <audio id="welcomeSound" controls="controls" preload="auto">
        <source src="welcome.ogg"></source>
        Your Browser does not support please use (Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 3+, Opera 10.5+, Safari 4+, IE 9+) browsers.
    </audio>
    <audio id="shutdownSound" controls="controls" preload="auto">
        <source src="shutdown.ogg"></source>
        Your Browser does not support please use (Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 3+, Opera 10.5+, Safari 4+, IE 9+) browsers.
    </audio>
    <p class="info">
        Use latest Browser Chrome or FireFox.
        <br /> If you usig Internet download manager please close it.
    </p>

    <a id="welcomeTxt" href="#">
    Welcome(Mouse hover here)
 </a>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a id="shutdownTxt" href="#">
  Shutdown(Mouse hover here)
 </a>
</section>

</html>
```

Comment: Since your javascript is in a template, you can just use template variables inside `{{ }}` as you would elsewhere in your template and loop using `{% for %}` etc

Comment: what if my javascript is external?

Comment: If it is in an external `.js` file, short answer seems to be "no". I have seen a few solutions on this site already, but none of them seemed ideal to me, and I have not tried them. However, I have used Django template tags in js within `<script></script>` tags quite a bit, and have never had issues with it. One thing I have done is put script tags and the enclosed javascript into it's own template, and `{% include %}` it when I need to use it. That way your script and template are kind of separate, which at least for me helps me focus on one of the other while working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a toy example of something that might work for you based on what you have. I have dynamically created JavaScript in this way before and have never had any issues with it, but **I cannot speak to performance or whether or not there is a better way**.  I assume there is a better way, but this way has, and continues to work for me, so I thought I would share it. For this example, `soundlinks` would have to be a list of paths to your audio files.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function() {
         // collecting elements
         {% for link in soundlinks %}
         var sound{{ forloop.counter }} = document.getElementById('sound{{ forloop.counter }}');
         var text{{ forloop.counter }} document.getElementById('text{{ forloop.counter }}');
         ...

          text{{ forloop.counter }}.onmouseover = function() {
              sound{{ forloop.counter}}.play();
              return false;
          };
         {% endfor %}
     };
    </script>
</head>
<html>
    <section>
        {% for link in soundlinks %}
        <audio id="sound{{ forloop.counter }}" controls="controls" preload="auto">
            <source src="{{ link }}"></source>
        </audio>
        <a id="text{{ forloop.counter }}" href="#">
            Hover to play audiofile #{{ forloop.counter }}
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </section>
</html>
```

It would be nice if you could use template tags in a `.js` file too, but AFAIK you cannot do this (though there are ways around this that I have seen on this site). One trick that I have used to keep my JavaScript and html visually separate, is to have the JS in its own template, and `{% include %}` it in another template. For example in `audioscript.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
     // collecting elements
     {% for link in soundlinks %}
     var sound{{ forloop.counter }} = document.getElementById('sound{{ forloop.counter }}');
     var text{{ forloop.counter }} document.getElementById('text{{ forloop.counter }}');
     ...

      text{{ forloop.counter }}.onmouseover = function() {
          sound{{ forloop.counter}}.play();
          return false;
      };
     {% endfor %}
 };
</script>
```

And then in another template:

```
<head>
{% include 'audioscript.html' %}
</head>
<html>
    <section>
        {% for link in soundlinks %}
        <audio id="sound{{ forloop.counter }}" controls="controls" preload="auto">
            <source src="{{ link }}"></source>
        </audio>
        <a id="text{{ forloop.counter }}" href="#">
            Hover to play audiofile #{{ forloop.counter }}
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </section>
</html>
```